# How does the Rune Knight's Storm Rune work?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, rune-knight

I have searched this explanation on the internet and on this website, but I have found nothing. In case this question may be a double, I am sorry. :)

So, how does the Storm Rune of Rune Knight work?

1. After invoking the rune, you can give advantage/disadvantage to a single roll as reaction and then the power is used, and the status expires.
   or
2. for all the duration of the prophetic state, you can give advantage/disadvantage to a roll as reaction. In other words, every turn, using the reaction, you have the possibility to give advantage/disadvantage to a roll.

For sure the 2) is much stronger and useful, however I am afraid it may be overpowered. On the other hand, the 1) is weak compared to the other 7-th rune option (hill rune). Is one of these interpretations correct?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### The Storm Rune's Prophetic State lasts for one minute and you can use the reaction multiple times in that minute

The Storm Rune states (emphasis mine)

> [...] In addition, **you can invoke the rune as a bonus action to enter a prophetic state for 1 minute** or until you're incapacitated. Until the state ends, when you or another creature you can see within 60 feet of you makes an attack roll, a saving throw, or an ability check, you can use your reaction to cause the roll to have advantage or disadvantage. **Once you invoke this rune, you can't do so again** until you finish a short or long rest.

What invoking the Rune does, is it sends you into a prophetic state for 1 minute. You grant yourself a buff that lasts for one minute. The description does not state any way for the state to end other than being incapacitated or the minute running up; so those are the only ways for it to end. For the entire duration of this state, the full minute, you can use your reaction in the new way described.

If using your reaction ended the state, it would explicitly say so. The thing you *can't* do is enter this minute-long state multiple times per short or long rest, which is what the final sentence is about. It isn't saying you can't use the reaction multiple times, it's saying you can't *invoke the rune* multiple times. What invoking the rune does is enter you into the prophetic state; using the reaction is *not* invoking the rune so it can be done freely.

The fire, frost, and hill runes all have a somewhat similar effect of granting a buff that lasts over time. Benefitting from those buffs does not count as invoking a rune, the buffs simply last for their duration. Invoking a rune is what *starts* the buff.